# To get index of an sorted array into another array in C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, sorting, indexing

I have 2 arrays say

sum:

```
68     
78     
25     
45
85
```

Index:

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

I did bubble sort on sum and got as:

```
25
45
68
78
85
```

Now, I need to know sort index array with respect to the sum array. So, my output of array should be:

```
2
3
0
1
4
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is a very simple solution that I never thought of and all credits goes to my project supervisor.. and it is.

Sort both the arrays under the same loop.. Thus when ever I will refer to any index, it will give me the sorted version.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend you sort the index array instead, and have the comparisons made using the values the indexes "point" to. So then you don't actually need to sort the "value" array just the "index" array.

Comment: well, I am working with a optimization sequence algorithm. Thus, I need to refer to my original sum array several times in the program. That is the reason I want to store the sequence(index) of sorted array sum in another array index. Because, I will be working on indexes than the value in the arrays. hope that make sense now.